# Can I solve this with a CTE, Pivot, a combination or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been asked to produce a rights matrix for our app, and I am wondering about the best approach.

If I have data that looks like this:

[image]

And the desired output looks something like this:

[image]

What is the best approach to be able to do this dynamically - so it is always up to date when new roles or menu options are added or flags changed? I have a feeling it's CTE-land (possibly + Pivot), but I just can't seem to bend my brain round it right now.

Naturally, there are many, many more roles and menu options!! (I can also get the menu item IDs not just the names, the data shown is already the result of a query I wrote).

Theoretically, the menus can have infinte depth, in reality the greatest we have is 4 levels,

```
CREATE TABLE #question (
    RoleID int NOT NULL,
    RoleName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    IsReadOnly bit NOT NULL,
    ParentMenuName varchar(100) NULL,
    MenuName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Regulierer bit NOT NULL,
    Station bit NOT NULL
) 


insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, NULL, N'Source Data', 0, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Source Data', N'Item', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Source Data', N'Stations', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Source Data', N'Cupboards', 1, 1)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, NULL, N'Print', 0, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Item List', N'by Item Number', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'by Item Number', N'ascending', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'by Item Number', N'descending', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Item List', N'by Description', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (1, N'Administrator', 0, N'Print', N'Item List', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (2, N'Assistant', 0, NULL, N'Source Data', 0, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (2, N'Assistant', 0, N'Source Data', N'Item', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (2, N'Assistant', 0, N'Source Data', N'Stations', 1, 0)
insert into #question (RoleID, RoleName, IsReadOnly, ParentMenuName, MenuName, Regulierer, Station) VALUES (2, N'Assistant', 1, N'Source Data', N'Cupboards', 1, 1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?  Is there a maximum depth to the menus?  Do they need to be in separate columns or would a string path work?

Comment: please add example data in text form instead of images

Comment: Please post your Sample data in a Consumable format, with DDL. [How to post a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: The end result is to be displayed as a report, anything I can tidy up to look like the example will do.

Comment: Gah, yes. Of course. DDL etc will take me a while. I tried to post in tab delimited format but it looked horrible. I am after general approaches more than detailed solutions right now.

Comment: Please answer @GordonLinoff 's Question about how deep the menus can get. This is relevant for the complexity of the query.

Comment: Sorry, depth is theoretically infinite, in practicality we have at most 4 levels - one more than I show above.

Comment: And this needs to be made in SQL? You couldn't just build an app that pulls out data and formats it for you pretty?

Comment: I'm interested in *if* it can be done using SQL. I can knock up an app easily enough, though, that's true.

Comment: So, did you solve the problem? Did my approach work out for you?

Comment: Sorry I have been on holiday. Tyron78 - see below. I think a procedural solution with an app is maybe the answer, but there is good stuff in your answer nonetheless! Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am better off going the route of dealing with this in an app not in SQL. The combination of many roles and many menu options seems to not lend itself to a SQL solution.

Thank you to all who put time into this.

Answer (score 2):

I worked a little on a solution. However, due to lack of time I couldn't finish it. But it should give you a general idea.
After all, you were right concerning CTE and Pivot. I used a combination of both in order to achieve the result.

At first I defined a table variable with your structure of #question (therefore you will find @question in my code).

In the first cte, I create a recursive tree of your menu - that's in order to cover the "dynamic depth" you mentioned. The next two ctes do the pivoting. In the following the pivoted values are joined together and transalted to 'h', 's' and '-'. The next cte prepares a blank tree structure and evaluates the depth of the menu entry. The last cte evaluates the top level Flag (X if any of the child values is h or s). Last but not least the last query handles the indenting of the menu name according to the depth of the menu entry and joins the values of admin and assistant to it.

Hopefully this is of help to you.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT 1 lvl
        ,q.RoleID
        ,q.RoleName
        ,q.MenuName TopLvlMenu
        ,q.IsReadOnly
        ,q.ParentMenuName
        ,q.MenuName
        ,CAST(q.MenuName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS MenuSrt
        ,q.Regulierer
        ,q.Station
    FROM @question q
    WHERE q.ParentMenuName IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT lvl + 1 lvl
        ,c.RoleID
        ,c.RoleName
        ,c.TopLvlMenu
        ,q.IsReadOnly
        ,q.ParentMenuName
        ,q.MenuName
        ,CAST(c.MenuSrt + ' - ' + q.MenuName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS MenuSrt
        ,q.Regulierer
        ,q.Station
    FROM cte AS c
    JOIN @question AS q ON q.ParentMenuName = c.MenuName
        AND q.RoleID = c.RoleID
        AND q.RoleName = c.RoleName
    WHERE q.ParentMenuName IS NOT NULL
    )
,cteHospital AS (
    SELECT MenuSrt
        ,Administrator
        ,Assistant
    FROM (
        SELECT MenuSrt
            ,RoleName
            ,CAST(Regulierer AS TINYINT) AS Regulierer
        FROM cte
        ) AS j
    PIVOT(MAX(Regulierer) FOR RoleName IN (
                Administrator
                ,Assistant
                )) AS p
    )
,cteStation AS (
    SELECT MenuSrt
        ,Administrator
        ,Assistant
    FROM (
        SELECT MenuSrt
            ,RoleName
            ,CAST(Station AS TINYINT) AS Station
        FROM cte
        ) AS j
    PIVOT(MAX(Station) FOR RoleName IN (
                Administrator
                ,Assistant
                )) AS p
    )
,cteAdminAss AS (
    SELECT ISNULL(h.MenuSrt, s.MenuSrt) MenuSrt
        ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CASE 
                    WHEN h.Administrator = 1
                        THEN 'h,'
                    ELSE ''
                    END + CASE 
                    WHEN s.Administrator = 1
                        THEN 's,'
                    ELSE ''
                    END, ''), '-,') AS Administrator
        ,ISNULL(h.Administrator,0) + ISNULL(s.Administrator, 0) AS Administrator_Num
        ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CASE 
                    WHEN h.Assistant = 1
                        THEN 'h,'
                    ELSE ''
                    END + CASE 
                    WHEN s.Assistant = 1
                        THEN 's,'
                    ELSE ''
                    END, ''), '-,') AS Assistant
        ,ISNULL(h.Assistant,0) + ISNULL(s.Assistant, 0) AS Assistant_Num
    FROM cteHospital h
    FULL JOIN cteStation s ON h.MenuSrt = s.MenuSrt
    )
,cteTree AS (
    SELECT MIN(lvl) lvl
        ,MenuName
        ,MenuSrt
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY MenuName
        ,MenuSrt
    )
,cteTopLevel AS(
    SELECT c.TopLvlMenu, CASE WHEN SUM(caa.Administrator_Num) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '-' END Administrator, CASE WHEN SUM(caa.Assistant_Num) > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '-' END Assistant
      FROM cteAdminAss caa
      JOIN cte c ON c.MenuSrt = caa.MenuSrt
      GROUP BY c.TopLvlMenu
    )
SELECT REPLICATE('          ', lvl - 1) + ct.MenuName AS MenuName
    ,COALESCE(ctl.Administrator, SUBSTRING(ca.Administrator, 1, LEN(ca.Administrator) - 1)) Administrator
    ,COALESCE(ctl.Assistant, SUBSTRING(ca.Assistant, 1, LEN(ca.Assistant) - 1)) Assistant
FROM cteTree ct
JOIN cteAdminAss ca ON ct.MenuSrt = ca.MenuSrt
LEFT JOIN cteTopLevel ctl ON ctl.TopLvlMenu = ct.MenuName
ORDER BY ct.MenuSrt, ct.lvl
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it and let you know how it goes!

Comment: This is not a full solution because, as mentioned in the question, there can be many role names not just 2. In reality, they would be the result of another query. But certainly some good clues there, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned: I didn't have time to finish it - it was only a "draft solution" to provide a general idea. However, since you decided to go with an app, that's OK. :-)